# Entity update in EntityManager

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, entitymanager

Describe briefly the whole situation. I have an entity

```
public class MovieEntity {
... 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MovieOtherTitle> otherTitles;
...
}
```

I save a movie in the database using the JPA Spring Data repository

```
this.movieRepository.save(movie);
```

Then I add another title to the film

```
final MovieOtherTitle movieOtherTitle = new MovieOtherTitle(otherTitle.getTitle(), otherTitle.getCountry());
movieOtherTitle.setMovie(movie);
movieOtherTitle.setUser(user);
this.entityManager.persist(element);
```

And when I want to display a list of titles for this movie, the list is BLANK

```
movie.getOtherTitles()
```

After recompile the application, everything is OK. WHY? It looks as if this entity did not refresh the list in real time. I have to compile the application again and only then you can see the elements in the list.

Comment: Can you show the `MovieOtherTitle`? Also when you create a new title, is the join column in the title table is correctly populated?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/u8FquKY8 Yes. All fields in the column are correctly completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.movieRepository.save(movie);
final MovieOtherTitle movieOtherTitle = new MovieOtherTitle(otherTitle.getTitle(), otherTitle.getCountry());
movieOtherTitle.setMovie(movie);
movieOtherTitle.setUser(user);

movie.getOtherTitles().add(movieOtherTitles);

this.movieReoository.save(movie);
```

So after calling 
    movie.getOtherTitles();
the list will not be empty

you can get the id of the otherTitle

```
movie.getOtherTitles().get(0).getId
```

Comment: I immediately need the ID of this saved object. The object movieOtherTitles will have it when added to the list?

Comment: Since you have the Cascade.All, then any call for the movie.save method will also save the new movieOtherTitles instance. did i get you question correctly?!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/AFDyhf5S This way I won't get an ID, which I need to add immediately to the list.

Comment: movie.getOtherTitles().get(0).getId

Comment: did you check it ?

Comment: I have a problem, because yesterday it worked, and today it is no longer working. https://zapodaj.net/ac2bf2eccf8bf.png.html

Comment: I have seen your another question and replied to it. you just forget to save the movie after adding the child list